# How can I clone Ubuntu OS disk from an existing azure virtual machine scale set to a new VM in azure?

Tags: server, cloud, clone, azure

Our client has a azure virtual machine scale set which is based on **Ubuntu default image Ubuntu server 18.04**. I want to create a new VM for them in which OS disk can have all software that are preinstalled in previous VMSS.

is there a way to clone existing OS to new VM without loosing data.

I have tried using capture on the instance but due to it being a VMSS and os disk being created from default image. it is not letting me do that.

Comment: "which is based on Ubuntu default image" [edit] your question with the version/distro of Ubuntu

Comment: Yes, see the Azure CONSOLE. But this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You do not do this from inside the instance so the OS inside it is not important.

Comment: Hi actually azure didnt have option of doing it

Comment: what do you mean? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/snapshot-copy-managed-disk?tabs=portal ?